# Code Error While Using SQL Output and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have the below stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 which is not generating any errors in SQL, but is generating one in the web application which states "'GetGenInfo_Delete01_01_22' expects parameter '@FPath', which was not supplied". I am fairly novice at SQL, but what I am trying to do is return a field to VB.NET before the row is deleted. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

```
ALTER Procedure  [dbo].[GetGenInfo_Delete01_01_22]
   @IDX int,
   @FPath varchar(100) OUTPUT
AS
Begin
SELECT @FPath  = (SELECT FilePath FROM GenInfo_E1_01_22 Where ID=@IDX) 

DELETE 
FROM GenInfo_E1_01_22
WHERE ID = @IDX
END
```

Here is the VB code calling the stored proc

```
                Using con As New SqlConnection(connstr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "GetGenInfo_Delete01_01_22"
            cmd.Parameters.Add("IDX", ID)
            Dim returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@FPath", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            GridView1.DataBind()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating parameter `returnParameter`, but you're not adding it to the parameters collection. Use `cmd.Parameters.Add(returnParameter)` prior to DB Call.

Comment: I added cmd.Parameters.Add(returnParamter) after returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
 but I am receiving an error in debug stating The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.

Comment: Now you're overdoing this :) don't use `cmd.Parameters.Add` twice for returnParameter, if you did it at `Dim` level, no need to do it again for the second time

Comment: Not Sure I follow :) I deleted cmd.parameters.add(returnParameter) but I thought it had to be added to add it to teh parameters list

Comment: For every parameter `Parameters.Add` need to be used only once, but in your updated example you had it twice for the same parameter: First `Dim returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add(...` - you create parameter *and in the same time* add it to the collection. And then several lines below you add it again - `cmd.Parameters.Add(returnParameter)` - this is the line I suggested, because originally you did not have `cmd.Parameters.Add` at the `Dim`. Now you have it there, so you don't need it here. Does the error go away if you keep it only at the Dim?

Comment: The updated code above generates an error on debug when I execute the reader stating "Procedure 'GetGenInfo_Delete01_01_22' expects parameter '@FPath', which was not supplied."

Comment: One more thing: change `returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` to `returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output`

Comment: AHH HAAA. I changed return type to OUTPUT and I received an error stating that "String[1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0." I am guessing a null entry for the OUTPUT field is causing the issue

Comment: More likely it's because you have not specified size of varchar parameter, try changing `cmd.Parameters.Add("@FPath", SqlDbType.VarChar)` to `cmd.Parameters.Add("@FPath", SqlDbType.VarChar,100)`

Comment: YAHTZEE! Thank you very much. Everything worked like a charm once I added a size.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an FPath parameter to cmd. Do it like this:

```
SqlParameter fpath = new SqlParameter();
fpath.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
fpath.ParameterName = "@FPATH";
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
```

Comment: He is already creating @FPath parameter, it just needs to be added to the collection. Oh and it's VB.NET

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that because on my screen the returnparameter lines look like they're commented out. I just skipped them